# Is it possible to find $g^k(x)$?

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

Given $g(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{x}$, is it possible to find an expression for $g^k(x)=(g\underbrace{\circ \cdots \circ}_k g)(x)$, where $k$ is some positive whole number?

For example, given $h(x)=\frac{x}{2}$, the expression for $h^k(x)$ is $h^k(x)=\frac{x}{2^k}$.

Comment: Trivially, $g^k(\pm\sqrt{2}) = \pm\sqrt{2}$, but I'm not sure what else to say about the function. I wish I knew more!

Comment: The only rational functions whose iterates I know a reasonable way of writing down are the fractional linear transformations $\frac{ax + b}{cx + d}$. Beyond that case I think things get quite complicated; see, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_dynamics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at
$$
g(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{x} = \frac{x^2 + 2}{2x}
$$

and cranking some iterations through the Maxima CAS, I get
$$
g^2(x) = 
{{x^4+12\,x^2+4}\over{4\,x^3+8\,x}} \\
g^3(x) = 
{{x^8+56\,x^6+280\,x^4+224\,x^2+16}\over{8\,x^7+112\,x^5+224\,x^3+
 64\,x}} \\
g^4(x) = 
{{x^{16}+240\,x^{14}+7280\,x^{12}+64064\,x^{10}+205920\,x^8+256256
 \,x^6+116480\,x^4+15360\,x^2+256}\over{16\,x^{15}+1120\,x^{13}+17472
 \,x^{11}+91520\,x^9+183040\,x^7+139776\,x^5+35840\,x^3+2048\,x}}
$$
This gives no simple pattern I am able to spot, just more or less
complicated rational functions with nominator degree $2^k$ and denominator degree $2^k - 1$, and the proper coefficients to go asymptotically to $h^k$.

Here are plots of $\text{id}, g, g^2, g^3, g^4, g^5$:

[image]
([Larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS0fs.png))

This is slightly more interesting, as we see that for $x > 0$ the series $g^k$ seems to iterate against a constant function, at value of the positive fixed point $x_+^*$ of $g$. (Similar for the negative arguments against $x_-^*$).

Going for the fixed points:
$$
x = g(x) = \frac{x^2 + 2}{2x} \Rightarrow \\
2 x^2 = x^2  + 2 \Rightarrow \\
x^2 = 2 \Rightarrow \\
x = \pm \sqrt{2}
$$

Comment: I guess it's not really easy, maybe impossible, to find $g^k(x)$ because the formulas for $g^2,g^3,g^4...$ grow longer to write down...

Comment: $g^4(x)$ is simpler than $${{x^{16}+240\,x^{14}+7280\,x^{12}+64064\,x^{10}+205920\,x^8+256256
 \,x^6+116480\,x^4+15360\,x^2+256}\over{16\,x^{15}+1120\,x^{13}+17472
 \,x^{11}+91520\,x^9+183040\,x^7+139776\,x^5+35840\,x^3+2048\,x}}$$. Coming up with a formula or recurrence for the coefficients might be possible, but do I want it?